# google maps api how to add circles around cities with url

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

[image: http://shrani.si/f/Z/u0/3LLz3huU/untitled.png]

I was reading this link but it is not the same

http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/maps/base-map-data/M775Ry3-vNM

How can in google map makes circles and urls around cities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the following link
http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/circle-overlay/circle-overlay.html

Use `new google.maps.Circle()` constructor. You should set the centre and specify the radius of the circle. Hollow effect can be created using `fillOpacity(0.0);`

There is also a rectangle constructor `new google.maps.Rectangle()`. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Rectangle

Answer (score 2):

Use `new google.maps.Circle()` with a combination of listeners like mouseover and click.

There are display options like opacity and color.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Circle

Your question is a bit too broad. If you have a more specific problem please edit it.